# What does XCode 'Clean' actually do?

Tags: xcode

I always choose to 'Clean' my project before archiving it in my XCode projects, but I don't actually know what it does.

I've searched the Internet and can't find the answer either.

If anybody knows could you please post it here?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [Xcode Glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/GlossaryDefinitions.html):

"**clean**: Removes all the product files, as well as any object files (.o files) or other intermediate files created during the build process."

Comment: the clean function was very helpful with my project when I deleted a XIB but the project was still referencing outlets somewhere....

Comment: The link changed to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/GlossaryDefinitions.html

Comment: So, what's the difference between intermediate files and Derived Data?